# Passing empty QString by reference

Tags: c++, qt

I have a method that has this signature

```
void SetFoo(QString& foo);
```

and I'm trying to pass an empty string inline, but none of the following compile

```
SetFoo("");
SetFoo(QString(""));
```

> (error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::SetFoo(QString)’)

but if I create a variable like this, it works.

```
QString emptyFoo = "";
SetFoo(emptyFoo);
```

Is there not a way to call the method without creating a variable explicitly?

NOTE:
      Everything seem to work in windows environment with using vc++ compiler but I encounter the above mentioned compilation error in linux environment using g++.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to pass in a temporary. The fact that the reference is non-const means it probably modifies it, which a temporary ruins the point of.

Comment: `Everything seem to work in windows environment with using vc++ compiler` vc++ has an evil extension allowing temporaries to bind to non-const references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a global object as a `const QString nullStr()` and use it everywhere- Somewhat similar to [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

Alternatively as billz mentions, a `const` reference to a temporary can exist, so making it `const Qstring&` [will enable the first 2 versions](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3RSRwM%241)

Regardless, you should change the reference to `const Qstring&` if you dont intend to modify it.

Comment: You should not define a non-const global null object. If it is modifiable, it may no longer be a null string for future usages.

Comment: Also, `QString("")` is not a null QString, it's an empty QString... ;) I fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

To bind a reference to a temporary object, you need `const` qualifier, if QString constructor takes `char*` input, try:

```
void SetFoo(const QString& foo);
```

It makes sense to pass a reference to outlived variable to SetFoo only:

```
void SetFoo(QString& foo);
QString s;
SetFoo(s);
```

.
    NOTE: Everything seem to work in windows environment with using vc++ compiler but I encounter the above mentioned compilation error in linux environment using g++.

VisualStudio is famous(good or bad way) for its C++ extentions, your code compiles on VS doesn't mean it's the C++ standards.  The better way is to turn on compile warning(level 4) when you write code, it should give you a warning for binding a reference to temporary object.
Also lookup C++ standard, lookup compiler manuals to make sure your code is portable.